# Show or hide text if no data/table is shown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have so many functions in my Rmarkdown file which is showing so many tables in output file. Also I have put a condition where there is no data in the table. Also I want to add a comment in the chunk itself.

So if the output of the chunk is blank then I only want to show "No Data to show summary" comment otherwise if the output of the chunk have any table or summary the before summary I want to show below comment and summary.

***Comment*** All location included in calculation.

rest of all chunks I don't want to show comment , only want to show "No Data to show summary" in word output . also i am using Cat to show tables and ### coming before comments that also i want to exclude.

````
```{r cars}
a <- letters[1:3]
t1 <- table(a, sample(a))

t1 <- 0

INC1<-ifelse(ncol(t1)==0,FALSE,TRUE)

if (INC1==FALSE) {
  cat("No Data to show summary")
}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do was check if there are any dimensions for the given variable(table), then created a boolean `TRUE/FALSE` based off some logic, each output is below

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, include=FALSE}

a <- letters[1:3]
t1 <- table(a, sample(a))
#t1 <- 0

  if(any(dim(t1)) ==TRUE){
    show_text = t1
  } else(show_text = "No Data to show summary")
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
show_text
```
````

[image]

[image]